# How much is “full damage” when not avoiding a dragon's Crush maneuver?

Tags: dragons, dnd-becmi

So I am planning on running an OD&D game and I came across this nifty ability:

> **Crush**: This maneuver is often used if the dragon surprises nonhuman
>   victims, or possibly against any opponents if the dragon is seriously
>   wounded. When crushing, the dragon actually lands on its victims. Each
>   may make a saving throw vs. death ray; success indicates complete
>   evasion of the crush, and no damage is inflicted. A victim may choose
>   to remain in the area, taking the full damage of the crush; if he
>   holds a weapon in hand, he may make an attack roll with a +4 bonus. If
>   he hits, he inflicts double damage. A small dragon can crush one
>   victim only. A large dragon can crush all in a 10' radius circle. A
>   huge dragon can crush all in a 20' radius circle.

Mainly: *A victim may choose to remain in the area, taking the full
damage of the crush; if he holds a weapon in hand, he may make an
attack roll with a +4 bonus. If he hits, he inflicts double damage.*

What I want to know is if the dragon deals max damage when it hits a non dodging foe, or if that is meant to to interpreted as it just rolling the damage with no chance of avoidance.

Comment: So you're asking: 'will the dragon do 30 damage or 5d6 against a non-dodging foe'... is that right?

Comment: Thanks everyone for you helpful answers! I am new to RPG.Stackexchance so I don't know the interface yet, but I am the original poster. You are correct that the rule is from AD&D, I did some looking after seeing that reply. Should be handy for the AD&D game I am planning on doing now though. I found it in The DD Rules Cyclopedia. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi, if you found an answer to your own question it would be really helpful if you were to type it up and self-answer. This will help anyone else who has similar problems :o)

Comment: Note that a rule found in the Rules Cyclopedia is not from Advanced D&D (AD&D), it's from a related game called Basic D&D, sometimes also called BECMI D&D or B/X D&D. It's not actually too important in this case, but it does explain why we were confused about what game your question is about.

Comment: Aside, you appear to have accidentally created more than one account. You will be unable to comment on or accept answers to your own question until you [merge your accounts using the instructions in the help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I finally found this in my copy of the Companion Rules, Dungeon Master Companion.  BECMI FTW!

Answer (score 10):

#### Full damage = what's rolled on the dice.

As written, the damage done to a non avoiding enemy is the full amount rolled, which isn't the same as "max damage" which could be inferred to mean "max possible score" on each die rolled.  The saving throw for this attack is a "save or suck" type save, so there's no half damage on offer.

> A victim may choose to remain in the area, taking the full damage of
>   the crush; if he holds a weapon in hand, he may make an attack roll
>   with a +4 bonus. If he hits, he inflicts double damage.

As written, if you choose not to avoid the crush attack, you take the damage rolled without modification.  The benefit for that choice is that you get a chance to deal serious damage to the dragon.  It's a trade off.

#### Where did this rule come from?

This crush attack is found in the Companion Rule set (BECMI D&D; TSR, 1984) in the Dungeon Master Companion (Book two, p. 30).

The *crush* attack uses the same damage as the *bite* attack per the damage table on page 30.  It varies by dragon color: for example, a large Black dragon would do 2d10+4 while a huge gold dragon would do 6d6+8.

Answer (score 5):

This rule seems to originate in Basic/Expert/Companion/Master/Immortals D&D. It's on p170 of the ***D&D Rules Cyclopedia***, with exactly this phrasing, and the table on p169 makes it clear that Crush damage is the same as Bite damage. AD&D1e didn't have anything like this.

The context makes it clear that if you fail the saving throw, or chose to remain in the area, you take full rolled damage, but not *maximum* damage or anything like that.